# Symfony DI pass new instance with arguments to constructor without creating bazillion service aliases?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have a super useful class `B` that have a single argument constructor.

I will use this class bazillion times in definition of other services in Symfony DI.

How can I avoid duplicating `B` service definition N times for the sake of creating aliases?

pseudo-code I would love to use:

```
A:
 aruguments:
  $someList:
   - B 'b1'
   - B 'b2'
   - B 'b3'
C:
 arguments:
  $someOtherList:
   - B 'b4'
   - B 'b999'
   - ...
D:
...
```

Why do I have so many `B`'s ? Because there is repeating behavior through my algorithm and `B` with single argument through constructor is enough to never repeat that behavior.

Why can't I roll `B` into `A` or `C`? `A` and `C` are collection/container style classes and I will have many of those. Would create explosion in classes created for each combination.

What's the code I would write without DI?

```
new A([
 new B('b1'),
 new B('b2'),
 new B('b3'),
]);

...

new C([
 new B('b4'),
 new B('b99'),
 ...
]);

...

new D([
 ...
```

So, how do I write equivalent symfony service definitions?

Comment: It's weird design. If `B` is a service, you shouldn't need to initialize it again and again with different parameters. `b1`, `b2`, etc look like parameters you should be passing the the `B` service at runtime, not something that the service would need at service instantiation.

Comment: It's final result of conjunction of: one to many; composition; DRY;

Comment: Also: Where would I store `B` arguments till runtime? In `A`/`C`/`D`? Those have nothing to do with `B` internals, and should not be aware of what dependencies `B` need. So where/how? Please turn your answer into actual answer. It's probably good alternative to solution I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I found is inline service definitions!

You can do that by prepending `!service` to an object containing necessary data:

```
A:
 aruguments:
  $someList:
   - !service { class:B, arguments: ['b1']}
   - !service { class:B, arguments: ['b2']}
   - !service { class:B, arguments: ['b3']}
C:
 arguments:
  $someOtherList:
   - !service { class:B, arguments: ['b4']}
   - !service { class:B, arguments: ['b999']}
   - ...
D:
```

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/alias_private.html#anonymous-services - more about anonymous services and how they work.